# Binding an ImageView

Tags: android, android-widget

Ok,so I've made a CursorAdapter in order to bind some textViews and a RatingBar from an Sql database in a ListView.Now I'm trying to add an ImageView which is not from the database but will appear in the ListView after the user has finished typing the input.A textView has .setText  and ratingBar has .setRating ...but I don't know what should I use for an ImageView.So my question what should I use to bind an Imageview with the other stuff in a ListView in the below method?Thank you

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
         String title=cursor.getString(
                  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BarsDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE));
          String body=cursor.getString(
                  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BarsDbAdapter.KEY_BODY));
          float rating=cursor.getFloat(
                  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BarsDbAdapter.KEY_RATING));



          mTitleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
          mBodyText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
          mRatingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
          mImageView=  (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

          mTitleText.setText(title);
          mBodyText.setText(body);
          mRatingBar.setRating(rating);
          mImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.shield);

    }
```